# Python - Removing 1 char from a series of nested lists

Tags: python, list

I've solved the problem with the code below, but I'm trying to understand a better way to strip out the zeros at the end of the each string of numbers because they throw off the calculation. The solution I have seems heavy handed, is there a more elegant way to solve this without a for loop removing the 0s?

## Coding Problem:

Determine the average of a series of numbers like this:

> 97 143 3 149 1 181 195 76 0
>
> 8042 4302 1273 3858 4019 8051 4831 7747 4887 768 6391 7817 2635 6203 0
>
> 1783 218 154 360 409 929 1503 428 73 1505 1868 1625 64 1613 0

```
import sys
inp = sys.stdin.readlines()
lin = []

for i in inp[1:]:
    lin.append(map(int,i.split()))
```

/---Crux----

```
for r in lin:
    del r[-1]
```

/-------------

```
for n in lin:
print int(round((sum(n) / float(len(n))))),
```

Any other critiques and constructive criticisms are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all in one go using slicing and list comprehension:

```
lin = [map(int,i.split())[:-1] for i in inp[1:]]
```

Comment: Thanks Julien this is very nice, what is it called when you put a for loop in one line like that?

Comment: It's called list comprehension. It can also by used with sets, dicts etc...

Answer (score -1):

As far getting the job done I think looks okay. Why not just do:

```
If r[-1] == 0:
    Del r[-1]
```

Comment: I was hoping to minimize the code I was using, is it normal for code to be as verbose as what I've got here?

Comment: I think the main thing you have to ask yourself is if you are taking all necessary precautions to avoid that trailing zero instance. If your code does that then yes, I would say that your code should suffice. The only redundant piece of code I'm seeing is the for loop deletion. If you want to use an approach like this maybe try    if 0 in list: list.pop(0)

Comment: I like the if 0 in list pop. It's very obvious what it's doing. I'll be sure to add the to my kit-bag, thanks for the update!

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just do:

```
lin=[]
for line in sys.stdin:
    lin.append([float(e) for e in line.split()[:-1]])
```

So that becomes a single line:

```
lin=[[float(e) for e in line.split()[:-1]] for line in sys.stdin]
```

Then your averages become:

```
avgs=[sum(e)/len(e) for e in lin]
>>> avgs
[105.625, 5058.857142857143, 895.1428571428571]
```